# C# MongoDB Searching

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to do a search across 2 different collections.  For example:

RecordCollection

```
 [{
     id: "1",
     name: "Henry"
     Values: [ "124", "243" ]
 }]
```

ValuesCollection

```
[{
    id: "124",
    Value: "Fox"
} ... ]
```

so the search query such as'fox' would pull back the 'Henry' record.

I know you could do something like:

```
var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
{
          { "text", records.Collection.Name },
          { "search", "fox" }
};

var commandResult = records.Collection.Database.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);
var response = commandResult.Response;
```

but that would yield no results since records collection doesn't contain 'fox'.

Comment: the only way to search over two collections is via two separate queries from your application.

Comment: Or, store your documents in a single collection. If documents need to be "typed", include a simple field for the type mapping and index it (again, if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a query only on a single collection in MongoDB. If you need 2 collections you need 2 queries.
MongoDB is a NoSQL db, and the mindset is all about multiple, short and fast queries. In this case after you get the `Record` you have the `Value`'s id, so getting it using the index should be quick.